Jetpack Compose - Compose View - Not found
I am using jetpack compose in an independant native android module inside a react native activity.
When i use ComposeView(context) its giving me this error.
Or when any class from androidx is called it ends up in the same exception.
added
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true 

            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/compose/ui/platform/ComposeView;
                                                                                                        
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/events.onair.dev/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes2.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~UefpzpJOSLpOFkuj1LO_ow==/events.onair.dev-CGS9xkgSNSxIJ_DApC1TlQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~UefpzpJOSLpOFkuj1LO_ow==/events.onair.dev-CGS9xkgSNSxIJ_DApC1TlQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~UefpzpJOSLpOFkuj1LO_ow==/events.onair.dev-CGS9xkgSNSxIJ_DApC1TlQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                        
                                                                                         

Here is my build file
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.mypj.videoplayer"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles( "consumer-rules.pro")
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.1"
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    //core
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")

    // Core library for saving and restoring UI state
    implementation ("androidx.savedstate:savedstate-ktx:1.2.1")

    //compose
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.01.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.6.0")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.2.0-rc01")

    implementation("androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.4.1")
    implementation("androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:1.4.1")
    implementation("androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.4.1")
    implementation("androidx.media3:media3-datasource-cronet:1.4.1")


    implementation ("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.32.0")
    implementation ("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1")
    implementation ("androidx.window:window:1.0.0")

    implementation ("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.11.0")
}

Kotlin version used is
kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
here are the dependancy in build.gradle for the project
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("io.sentry:sentry-android-gradle-plugin:4.11.0")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        // classpath("com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:7.1.0")
    }

Please help me fix this error. i have compose only in this module .
